# JSON Jolt If Else

Tags: json, jolt

could someone help me with this?
If 01 is given in "decision", we display from field A under the name "First", and if it is 02, we display from field A under the name "Second".
In both cases, we add "xyz" to the value in field A at the end.

Input:

```json
{
  "Some": {
    "Numbers": {
      "Number": [
        {
          "Int": {
            "A": "45618975618"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "Z": {
      "X": [
        {
          "decision": {
            "value": [
              "01"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output for a 01:

```json
{
  "A" : {
    "B" : {
      "First" : {
        "A" : "45618975618XYZ"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following spec

```json
[
  {//conditionally match the respective values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@(0,Some.Z.X[0].decision.value[0])": { // comparison criteria
        "01": {
          "@(2,Some.Numbers.Number[0].Int.A)": "A.B.First.A"
        },
        "02": { 
          "@(2,Some.Numbers.Number[0].Int.A)": "A.B.Second.A"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
   //add literal "XYZ" to the end of the returned value
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "=concat(@(1,&),'XYZ')"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]